# Duvida sobre url ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, crud

Estou desenvolvendo um crud simples com ajax e jquery e me deparei com a seguinte questão...

```
$('#btnDelete').unbid().click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'ajax',
            method: 'post',
            async: false,
            url: url,
        })
    })
```

Notem que minha url conta apenas com url: url, em outro local há um script parecido porém com a url diferente. Qua seria a diferença ?

```
$.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>usuario/remover',
            type: 'POST',
            data: dados,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No primeiro caso (URL: url):**

url é uma variável definida previamente no código do seu arquivo .js onde está a função que mencionou, por exemplo:

```
var url = 'http://seusite.com.br/api/getUser'

$('#btnDelete').unbid().click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'ajax',
            method: 'post',
            async: false,
            url: url,
        })
    })
```

**No segundo caso (php):**

Está usando php para pega a URL base. Por exemplo:

`echo base_url("blog/post/123");`

Irá retornar http://seusite.com.br/blog/post/123

Assim como:

`echo base_url();`

Irá retornar http://seusite.com.br/

Mas por favor não realize a inserçao de codigo html dentro de arquivos .js é extremamente não recomendado. Se você precisar fazer isso, pode realizar dando echo nas variaveis no DOM e então pegar com o javascript.

```
<!-- snip -->
<div id="dom-target" style="display: none;">
    <?php 
        echo base_url();
    ?>
</div>
<script>
    var div = document.getElementById("dom-target");
    var myData = div.textContent;
</script>
<!-- snip -->
```